# Can sour cream be whipped?

Tags: whipped-cream

Will whipping sour cream result in something with a texture similar to whipped cream? How about a mix of whipping cream and sweet cream? I want a pie topping with a sour taste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sour cream will not whip like whipping cream.  I would use a combination for your application.  Whip your cream.  Fold in sour cream as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It was delicious and I'd make it again.